# Batch script to delete all records from a SQL Server CE database table

Tags: batch-file, sql-server-ce

Need a batch script to delete all records in a SQL Server CE database table. Don't know if its possible, I'm weak in scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my SqlCeCmd/SqlCeCmd40 command line utility from a batch file, with a command line like:

```
sqlcecmd -d "Data Source=C:\mydb.sdf" -q "DELETE * FROM MyTable"
```

(Or DROP the table and recreate with CREATE TABLE - faster)

Download from http://sqlcecmd.codeplex.com

Comment: Nice little thing! Thank you!